# Obtener JSON en PHP mediante cURL

Tags: php, json, php5, curl

Tengo un servidor Win con PHP: 5.4.45 y cURL: 7.42.1, quiero obtener un JSON de una web concreta para ello utilizo el siguiente código:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $data;
}

$json_string = 'https://api.sheety.co/uk-theme-parks';


$jsondata = file_get_contents_curl($json_string);
var_dump($jsondata); echo '<br>';

$obj = json_decode($jsondata); 
var_dump($obj);
echo '<br>';
?>
```

En mí máquina recibo la siguiente respuesta:

```
bool(false)
NULL
```

He probado en PhpFiddle y parece que el código es correcto. He probado con códigos básicos de cURL por si pudiera ser alguna configuración de FW de mi entorno y cURL funciona correctamente.

Comment: Por lo que sea, tu función no está pudiendo descargar el contenido de la URL. He probado tu código en una máquina de prueba y me funciona correctamente con PHP 5.6.40. Por cierto, que existe una función de PHP llamada 'file_get_contents'.

Comment: Si pero la función por defecto file_get_contents me daba unos problemas con el certificado SSL, es por eso que he implementado file_get_contents_curl.

Comment: Supongo que estarás usando esa función porque la viste en esta respuesta en stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more). No tengo claro que eso resuelva tu problema. Quizás el mismo error de certificado que te dé una función, también te la esté dando curl.
Prueba a añadir dos opciones más:
```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);```
Otra opción es usar la función 'file_get_contets' usando el parámetro 'context'.

Comment: Mismo error añadiendo las 2 opciones que me comentas. Usando file_get_contents sin utilizar el parámetro 'context'. Los siguientes warning: 1) SSL operation failed with code 1 2) Failed to enable crypto 3) failed to open stream: operation failed.

Comment: Probé tu url con un fetch de javascript y me devuelve esto: `Bad Request. Missing project and sheet name in the URL. To see how to construct URLs visit https://sheety.co/docs`. Creo que tu problema parte de ahí

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function do_curl($url_json){
    $response = array();

    $ch = curl_init($url_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$json_string = 'https://api.sheety.co/uk-theme-parks';

$jsondata = do_curl($json_string);
//var_dump($jsondata); echo '<br>';

$obj = json_encode(json_decode($jsondata), TRUE); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($obj);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Prueba con sólo 2 OPT:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

Comment: El mismo resultado, null.

Comment: te dejo un post de overflow en inglés que he encontrado, pude ser por el tiempo del servidor que no lo recoge bien o el ssl, prueba las posibles soluciones:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Answer (score 1):

Hola debes convertirlo a json:

```
$data = curl_exec( $ch );
$request = json_decode($data);
$request = $request->response; 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($request);
echo "</pre>";
// O manejarlo como objeto
foreach ($request as $key => $respuesta){
  //tu codigo
}
```